# How can I find all the Grand-Parent directories where a file resides

Tags: powershell

I would like to find all the grand-parent directories where a file exists using PowerShell but can't think of how to do it. I figured I need to do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter MyApp.exe -Recurse | format-table Directory
```

Suppose I have the file in the following places:

```
C:\test\AppA\201608114\MyApp.exe
C:\test\AppA\20160812a\MyApp.exe
C:\test\AppA\201608136\MyApp.exe
C:\test\AppB\201607115\MyApp.exe
C:\test\AppB\201607104\MyApp.exe
C:\test\OtherApps\AppC\201606234\MyApp.exe
```

So in the above example I would like Powershell to output:

```
C:\test\AppA
C:\test\AppB
C:\test\OtherApps\AppC
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Powershell. Almost at the point of just writing a Perl/Python script for this but figured I'd give PowerShell a shot at it first

Comment: Those are all grandparent directories...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the parent of the files' directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter MyApp.exe -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Directory.Parent.FullName
} | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Comment: This is close but they aren't distinct

Comment: @Denis Now they are.

Comment: awesome, also just figured out how to make them unique. This isn't too bad.